# The Definite Article with the Names of Festivals

Tags: definite-articles

I have noticed that the definite article ***the*** is always dropped before religious festivals, such as ***Easter, Passover, Christmas, Eid-al-Fitr***, etc. However, it is always used before film festivals , such as ***the Cannes Film Festival, the Chicago International Film Festival, the Canberra International Film Festival***, etc. The problem is with the names of cultural festivals around the world. Some are used with the definite article, others are not. ***Burning Man Festival and the Boston Seafood Festival*** are just two examples.
I am wondering why the definite article is used with some cultural festivals and dropped with others. And is there a reasonable explanation for this or does it depend on the context ?

Comment: How many Passovers are there? And how many film festivals?

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think it is just one which refers to the Exodus, but film festivals are too many to be counted. But why?

Comment: You certainly wouldn't say _this year's **the** Boston Seafood Festival_ . . .

Comment: And you would say _the Christmas before last_, for example.

Comment: @Tinfoil & Kate: l agree with you that there are exceptions when they are premodified by other words. But I'm looking for an answer to why there is different variation with cultural festivals.